# Checking whether there is an input field in an HTML Form

Tags: javascript, html

How can I check if there is a input field in my HTML Form. 
I try a code like this:

```
if(document.getElementById('fieldID') != 'null') {
    alert('Some alert');
}
```

But this is not working. How can i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null shouldn't have quotes as it isn't a string, but an absolute value. Use this:

```
if(document.getElementById('fieldID') != null){
         alert('Some alert');
}
```

Comment: Not `NULL` but `null`, I believe?

Comment: Ah, of course, used to the whole C# syntax. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I remember that both ways work, is that not true?

Comment: Not true :) Try eval'ing `NULL` in the DevTools console or something.